# Jenkins: old builds still appear as running - is that bad?

Tags: jenkins

I open up my Integration tests build history and a few of them are shown as running (and can't be stopped)

I think this is better illustrated with a picture:
http://d.pr/i/HDwJ

Is that a problem, is it a bug, is it fixable, is it my fault?